# How to execute custom gradle task for debugging from IDE (Netbeans)

Tags: gradle, netbeans

We are using custom source set and hence the default gradle tasks "run" and "debug" cant be used from netBeans to launch.

Please let me know the steps to configure Netbeans such that when I clik "Debug Project", I need to execute custom gradle task :-

***gradle -PmainClass=xxx.TestDelMe execute***

Sample build.gradle with execute task :-

```
sourceSets {
    integTest{
        java.srcDir 'src/integTest/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/integTest/resources'
    }
}

/**
* This task creates the jar for the compiled test code.
*/
task integTestJar (type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.integTest.output
    appendix = 'integ-tests'
}
    /*
    gradle -PmainClass=xxx.TestDelMe execute
    */
    task execute(type:JavaExec) {
        main = mainClass
        debug = true
        dependsOn 'assemble', 'integTestJar'
        classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.integTest.compileClasspath
    }
```

[image]

Thanks,
Subra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found below workaround :-

Enable debugging for JavaExec type task by using the flag "debug=true" (as below)

```
/*
    gradle -PmainClass=xxx.TestDelMe execute
    */
    task execute(type:JavaExec) {
        main = mainClass
        **debug = true**
        dependsOn 'assemble', 'integTestJar'
        classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.integTest.compileClasspath

    }
```

Create a custom task for execute from

[image]

Launch the custom task by right clicking the project

[image]

Now the JVM will wait on port 5005 till netbeans attaches to it as below

[image]

[image]

Then setbreak point and enjoy debugging

[image]